# Open Optionsmenu from Actionbar with Hardware Options Button present? (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

In my App, I use a custom Actionbar made with the Android Action Bar Style Generator.
(http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)
On devices such as the Nexus 4 which dont have a hardware button but those 3 dots on the right side of the actionbar to open the optionsmenu in the upper right corner of my application the style is correct but on other devices the optionsmenu inflates on the bottom of my app with a standard style.

How can i get my ActionBar to always have these three dots at the right side to open my custom-style optionsmenu in the upper-right corner of my app, even if there's a hardware button present?

Or, in other words, how do i get my application to believe there's no hardware options button and handle the optionsmenu as it does on e.g. a Nexus 4?

I'd be very grateful for any help on how to achieve this.

Best regards, Claas M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with same problem today and finally found answer here: [Options Menu does not appear in Action Bar on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010876/options-menu-does-not-appear-in-action-bar-on-some-devices/26011059#26011059).

Tested on real Nexus S device with Android 4.1.2 and app *minSdkVersion* set to *15*