# Options Menu does not appear in Action Bar on some devices

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have an options menu in the action bar, and it does not appear on certain devices which have hardware menu button. I must make it appear in the action bar despite having a hardware button...
How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this in your `onCreate` method:

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
            .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: what import is the Field?

Comment: import java.lang.reflect.Field